# I do not understand why the icon color doesn't change on Blogger homepage individually?

Tags: javascript, css, blogger

I am trying to put different color on eye depending on how much people have visited.

On blogger static post, the code work great. But when I go to my homepage, it doesn't change the eye color base on numeric value that I have set it out. It only show 1 color only instead of individually with different numeric value and it will change the color every time i clicked on load more article on the bottom of the homepage.

What is the problem here? I hope someone could tell me. I am not really good at coding, just find out the code from internet and mixed it up after by looking through other tutorial.

Here's the website, https://www.nakbebel.my

Here's the code that I am working on

Please focus on // coloring eye section.

```
<!-- code for views count -->
<script src='https://cdn.firebase.com/v0/firebase.js' type='text/javascript'/>
<script>
/*<![CDATA[*/
$.each($("a[name]"), function (i, e) {
  var elem = $(e).parent().find("#postviews");
  var blogStats = new Firebase("https://sh-v-3da10-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/" + $(e).attr("name"));
  blogStats.once("value", function (snapshot) {
    var data = snapshot.val();
    var isnew = false;
    if (data == null) {
      data = {};
      data.value = 0;
      data.url = window.location.href;
      data.id = $(e).attr("name");
      isnew = true;
    }

    // original count
    var count = data.value;

    // coloring eye
$.fn.colorize = function () {
   return this.each(function() {
      var $this = $(this);
      $this.css({color: count < 200 ? "grey"
                      : count < 500 ? "yellow"
                      : "red"});
   });
};
$("i.far.fa-eye").colorize();



    // count separated by comma
    var separatedCount = count.toString()
      .split('').reverse().join('')
      .match(/\d{1,3}/g).join(',')
      .split('').reverse().join('');

    elem.text(separatedCount);

    data.value++;
    if (window.location.pathname !== "/") {
      if (isnew) blogStats.set(data); else blogStats.child("value").set(data.value);
    }
  });
});
/*]]>*/
</script>
```

I am expecting some easy way to fixed this issue. I hope someone could help me. The only problem that I want is the code to synchronise both blogger homepage element (eye icon color) and blogger static post element (eye icon color) depending on their numeric value from post views.

---

Here's the attempt that I have done with picture.

1st Attempt.

I use this code

```
    // coloring eye
let eye = document.getElementById("matamata");

if (count < 300) {eye.style.color = "grey";} 
else if (count >= 300 && count < 600) {eye.style.color = "yellow";}
else if (count >= 600 && count < 1000) {eye.style.color = "orange";} 
else {eye.style.color = "red";}
```

Here's the result of this attempt from homepage view and post view.

Homepage view
[image: It only work on 1st article but not the other.]

Post view

[image: This work fine.]

2nd Attempt

I use this code.

```
    // coloring eye
$.fn.colorize = function () {
   return this.each(function() {
      var $this = $(this);
      $this.css({color: count < 200 ? "grey"
                      : count < 500 ? "yellow"
                      : "red"});
   });
};
$("i.far.fa-eye").colorize();
```

The result for this attempt:

Homepage view

[image: it does work to every article, but as a whole not individually.]

Post view

[image: On post view this attempt work fine too.]

As a result i would prefer to choose 2nd attempt, but the problem is this attempt showing result as a whole code for icon eye color instead individual article on homepage view perspective.

Both code give good result when showing from post view perspective.

Comment: Please post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: my other attempt was not doing good, But the result only work for 1st article on blogger homepage, the other article doesn't work. 

this is example code that i found from internet that I use before, 

let visits = document.getElementById("postviews");
let eye = document.getElementById("eye");

if (visits < 50) {
  eye.style.color = "red";
} else if (visits >= 50 && visits < 100) {
  eye.style.color = "orange";
} else if (visits >= 100 && visits < 150) {
  eye.style.color = "yellow";
} else {
  eye.style.color = "green";
}

Comment: Pleas update the question instead of posting code in comments. Just click [edit] and add HTML, CSS and fontawsome from a CDN

Comment: I am sorry. I have just edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- IDs need to be unique
- The fn needs to be outside the each
- The count has to be passed to the function

Here is a working version without FN

You need to call this AFTER the icons have been rendered
i.e. AFTER the `$.each($("a[name]"), function (i, e) { ............ });` NOT inside

```js
$("i.far.fa-eye").each(function() {
  const count = +$(this).closest(".entry-meta").find(".viewsini").text().replace(/\D/,"");
//  console.log(count)
  $(this).css({color: count < 200 ? "grey" : count < 500 ? "yellow" : "red" });
})
```

```css
.fa-eye:before {
    content: "";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="entry-meta">
  <span class="entry-author">
<span class="by">Oleh:</span><span class="author-name">52UL</span></span>
  <span class="entry-time"><time class="published" datetime="2020-07-29T20:42:00+08:00">29.7.20</time></span><span class="postviews1" style="margin-left:5px; "><a name="4567839109293122938"></a><i class="far fa-eye" id="matamata" style="color: grey;"></i><span id="post-4567839109293122938"><span class="viewsini" id="postviews">1,849</span></span>
  Views <span class="menarik">MENARIK</span><span class="hangat">HANGAT</span></span>
</div>
<div class="entry-meta">
  <span class="entry-author">
<span class="by">Oleh:</span><span class="author-name">mhdazln</span></span>
  <span class="entry-time"><time class="published" datetime="2020-07-29T20:38:00+08:00">29.7.20</time></span><span class="postviews1" style="margin-left:5px; "><a name="5430741819652172389"></a><i class="far fa-eye" id="matamata" style="color: grey;"></i><span id="post-5430741819652172389"><span class="viewsini" id="postviews">207</span></span>
  Views <span class="menarik">MENARIK</span><span class="hangat">HANGAT</span></span>


</div>

<hr />

<h1>Blog post</h1>
<div class="entry-meta">
<div class="align-left">
<span class="entry-author"><span class="author-avatar-wrap"><span class="author-avatar lazy-ify" data-image="//3.bp.blogspot.com/-pI9uAjf9vsY/XvDqs0wJtkI/AAAAAAAACQc/8QRyrYzMrNUP5lisRPNuHIy2WcBlKowAQCK4BGAYYCw/w72-h72-p-k-no-nu/123.jpg" style="background-image:url(https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-pI9uAjf9vsY/XvDqs0wJtkI/AAAAAAAACQc/8QRyrYzMrNUP5lisRPNuHIy2WcBlKowAQCK4BGAYYCw/w29-h29-p-k-no-nu/123.jpg)"></span></span>
<span class="by"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">By:</font></font></span><span class="author-name"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">52 UL</font></font></span></span>
<span class="entry-time"><time class="published" datetime="2020-07-29T20:42:00+08:00"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">29.7.20</font></font></time></span><span class="postviews1" style="margin-left:5px; "><a name="4567839109293122938"></a><i class="far fa-eye" id="matamata" style="color: grey;"></i><span id="post-4567839109293122938"><span class="viewsini" id="postviews"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">858</font></font></span></span><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">Views</font></font><span class="menarik"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">ATTRACT</font></font></span><span class="hangat"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">WARM</font></font></span></span>


</div>
<div class="align-right">
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, it does work now for blogger homepage but doesn't work on blogger post now. Just showing grey eye color.

Comment: You obviously need to run the same code when finished loading the blog post. The code is the same. See update

Comment: Yes you right. You did answer the question. I will try to find the solution for the other problem. thank you very much sir. 

If you don't mind to help further, what I am trying to say is, if you click one of the article, the viewing page of the article it doesn't work according to the count values. So now I have to find the way to solve this. I am not good with code. So your help just now really help a lot.

Comment: On the blog page you can add this anywhere  `$(function() { $("i.far.fa-eye").each(function() {
  const count = +$(this).closest(".entry-meta").find(".viewsini").text();
  $(this).css({color: count < 200 ? "grey" : count < 500 ? "yellow" : "red" });
}); });`

Comment: I tried. It doesn't work too.

Comment: You put it INSIDE the loop! Put this OUTSIDE the each AFTER the `$.each($("a[name]"), function (i, e) { ............ });` BEFORE the `/*]]>*/</script>`  - like this:


`$("i.far.fa-eye").each(function() {   const count = +$(this).closest(".entry-meta").find(".viewsini").text();   $(this).css({color: count < 200 ? "grey" : count < 500 ? "yellow" : "red" }); });/*]]>*/</script>`

Comment: Sir, I hope you could help me with another question regarding this. 

I would like to change the count to exact number that I want. 

< 1000 to grey 
< 5000 to yellow 
and the rest is red. 

Unfortunately I have made the numeric value to have thousand separator with , . I think that is the reason it doesn't work when I want to change the count value. Is there any way to solve it?

Comment: See update: `const count = +$(this).closest(".entry-meta").find(".viewsini").text().replace(/\D/,"");`

Comment: You helped a lot. Thank you very much sir.